# Embedded GATE - loading pipeline with complicated rules

Tags: java, gate

I have used Embedded GATE ([BatchProcessApp](https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/javadoc/src-html/sheffield/examples/BatchProcessApp.html)) and I have developed a web application based on that and generate the annotations as a XML file. Therefore, I can create my own pipeline through GATE GUI and save it as an application file (.xgapp) and upload it to the web application. From the web application, I can upload my corpora and select the already uploaded pipeline. Till now, everything is working perfectly.

In my last pipeline, I have a very complicated rules which loading that into GATE GUI takes 50 to 70 seconds but It is working fine at GATE GUI.
**The problem is**, I can not process my corpus through web application with this pipeline and always I got **gc overhead limit exceeded** error. This error will happen when the java code wants to load the .xgapp file. Here is the line of code which generate error:

```
myController = (CorpusController) PersistenceManager.loadObjectFromFile(gappPath);
```

Which **gappPath** is: gappPath = new File(GateHome, Pipeline);

I'd like to mention, I didn't any change in my code which it is working perfectly for other pipelines.

Could you please help me to solve the problem?

Thanks.
Amin

Answer (score 0):

50 to 70 seconds for application loading is really toooo much. Is there any way to simplify rules or split process in to several steps?
For example:

a) Prepare your data step-by-step generating features via simplified apps containing your rules

b) Run BatchLearning process as separated application over corpus prepared.

Unfortunately, from your description it's not possible to understand what is the real problem.